# How to fix my carousel controls and indicators

Tags: html

I have a problem on my carousel using controls and indicators, which does not make my photos slide through other pictures, the only picture I see is the one you marked as active.

```
<div class="col-6 text-center m-auto ">

            <div id="example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#example" data-slide-to='0' class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#example" data-slide-to='1'> </li>
                    <li data-target="#example" data-slide-to='2'> </li>
                    <li data-target="#example" data-slide-to='3'> </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active"> <img src="/setup/img/portfolio.jpg" alt="port" class="d-block w-100 height-100"></div>

                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="/setup/img/mypic.jpg" alt="ports" class="d-block w-50"></div>

                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="/setup/img/code.jpg" alt="port1" class="d-block w-50"></div>

                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="/setup/img/about.jpg" alt="port2" class="d-block w-50"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- controls-->
                <a href="#example" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#example" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I expect to be able to use my controls or even even just the indicators.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So we can better help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like using bootstrap.

Please double check that you have links for jQuery and Bootstrap.js in your code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```